# grails default values

Tags: grails, default-value

I have an application written in grails.
I want to add a new domain class with default initial values.
These values should appear as **default** or **initial values** 
under the create view.
I mean, the generated inout field tag should have this value as
an attribute.

The class (simplified) look as follows:

```
class Whatever{
static constraints = {
    myString(blank:false, nullable:false)
     }
    String myString = "hallo"
```

The generated view looks as follows:

```
...
<td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean: whatEverInstance, field: 'myString', 'errors')}">
   <g:textField name="serviceReview" value="${fieldValue(bean: whatEverInstance, field: 'myString')}" />
</td>
```

For some unknown reason when the source of render page has looks as follows:

```
<td valign="top" class="value ">
    <input type="text" name="myString" value="" id="myString" />
</td>
```

I was expecting **value="hallo"**.
I mean:

```
<td valign="top" class="value ">
    <input type="text" name="myString" value="hallo" id="myString" />
</td>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Luis

EDIT:

My create method is as follows:

```
 def create = {
        def whateverInstance        = new Whatever()
        whateverInstance.properties = params

        return [whateverInstance: whateverInstance]
    }
```

But the create method is called **after** the form is filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is you whatEverInstance bean being set in the controller's `create` setup action?

```
def create = {
    [whateverInstance: new Whatever()]
}
```

You could test the value of whateverInstance in the gsp with:

${whateverInstance}

Answer (score 2):

```
 int varm

 static mapping = {       
   table 'Test55'
   id column: "kid", name:"kid"
   version false 
   varm column: 'varm', name: 'varm', sqlType: 'numeric(1) default 1'
}
```

This works